# How to update python x.x to python x.x keeping all the packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, updates, insert-update

I am a python 3.8 user. So, to stay updated I want to update my python 3.8 to 3.9. But I have a huge number of packages installed in python 3.8. Is there any method to keep the packages and update python 3.8 to 3.9?

Comment: I don't think it's wise at this moment. For instance `pyarrow` cannot be installed using `pip` in python 3.9 at the moment (and maybe some more packages)

Comment: Use `pip freeze` to create a requirements file and use `pip -r requirements.txt` with your new Python installation to install those packages. If something doesn't work, do it manually. I did exactly this when I moved from Python 3.6 to Python 3.9 last week.

Comment: You can't avoid reinstalling all those packages.  Attempts  to take shortcuts are likely to end in misbehaviour and confusion, as illustrated by similar questions on SO that people asked only *after* making the attempt and failing. I would give @leofromtj 's proposal for automating the reinstall a try. But examine the output very carefully afterwards, to pick up individual failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pip
from subprocess import call
for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    call("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```

Comment: please format your answer for readability purposes.